# Not able to enter nodes manually in singly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm coding out Singly Linked List functions for practice. While testing out the different functions I decided to put in an auto-populate feature, instead of using *Insert Head* or *Insert Tail* functions to make a list to test out the *Deletion* and *Reverse* functions. I didn't want to call the *Insertion* function repeatedly and create a list for testing each time.

However, that did not work for me, it did not work as intended. It produced garbage values and exited compilation instead.

I am not able to find the reason behind it. The rest of the code has no errors and is behaving as expected.

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
  struct node* head;
  int ch,x,pos;
  void display(struct node *);
  void insert_head(struct node **, int);
  void insert_tail(struct node **, int);
  void insert_pos(struct node **, int , int);
  void delete_first(struct node **);
  void delete_last(struct node **p);
  void delete_pos(struct node **,int);
  void delete_node(struct node **,int);
  void reverse(struct node **);
  
  
  head=NULL;//pointer to the first node

  while(1)
  {
    display(head);
    printf("\n1..Insert head\n");
    printf("2..Insert tail\n");
    printf("3..Display\n");
    printf("4..Delete First\n");
    printf("5..Delete a node\n");
    printf("6..Delete at position\n");
    printf("7..Reverse a List\n");
    printf("8..Insert at a position\n");
    printf("9..Delete last node\n");
    printf("10..Autopopulate\n");
    printf("11..Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:printf("Enter the number\n");
           scanf("%d",&x);
           insert_head(&head,x);
           break;                   
        case 2:printf("Enter the number\n");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            insert_tail(&head,x);
            break; 
        case 3:display(head);
            break;
        case 4:delete_first(&head);
            break;
        case 5:printf("Enter the value of the node\n");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            delete_node(&head,x);
            break;
        case 6:printf("Enter the position");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            delete_pos(&head,x);
            break;  
        case 7:reverse(&head);
            break;
        case 8:printf("Enter the value and the position of the node..");
            scanf("%d %d",&x,&pos);
            insert_pos(&head,x,pos);
            break;
        case 9:delete_last(&head);
            break;
        case 10:printf("Entered autopopulate\n");       
            /* insert_head(&head,5);
            insert_head(&head,4);       //forced to use this instead of the code below
            insert_head(&head,3);
            insert_head(&head,2);
            insert_head(&head,1); */

            //i coded this out hoping for practise with manually making nodes and linking
            //them together and to head pointer, however it generated garbage values
            //and I'm not able to figure out why
            struct node *list1, *list2, *list3, *list4, *list5;
            head=list1;
            list1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            list1->data=1;
            list1->next=list2;

            list2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            list2->data=2;
            list2->next=list3;

            list3=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            list3->data=3;
            list3->next=list4;

            list4=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            list4->data=4;
            list4->next=list5;

            list5=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            list5->data=5;
            list5->next=NULL;
                
            break;
        case 11: exit(0);
     }
  }
}
```

The output I'm hoping for is:

```
1->2->3->4->5->NULL
```

However, I instead end up getting garbage outputs such as:

```
17744->
```

After which the program exits compilations instead of repeating the 'asking for user input' process.

I hope for some *pointers* to where I'm going wrong.

In all seriousness, I'm thanking in advance all those who set aside their time and read said question. Thank you.

Comment: `list1->next=list2;` but `list2` doesn't yet have a value (see Yunnosch' answer).

Comment: `head=list1; list1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` Need to swap the order of those. That is, `list1` needs to be valid before making that the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

All these lines

```
head       =list1;
list1->next=list2;
list2->next=list3;
list3->next=list4;
list4->next=list5;
```

use not yet initialised pointers.

If you reverse the steps that problem is solved.

```
/* malloc list5 */
list5->next=NULL;
/* malloc list4 */
list4->next=list5;
/* malloc list3 */
list3->next=list4;
/* malloc list2 */
list2->next=list3;
/* malloc list1 */
list1->next=list2;
head       =list1;
```

(*I have not copied your malloc lines, because they conflict with recommendation to not cast malloc results. The data-writing lines are irrelevant for the problem, though of course needed.*)